# FFMPEG - Transition effect in slideshow didn't run?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a problem when I want to make a slideshow video from pictures

ffmpeg -i img%03d.png
-filter_complex "color=c=black:r=60:size=1280x800:d=7.0[black][0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,zoompan=d=25*4:s=1280x800,fade=t=out:st=3.0:d=1.0:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,zoompan=d=25*4:s=1280x800,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1.0:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+3.0/TB[v1];[black][v0]overlay[ov0];[ov0][v1]overlay=format=yuv420"-c:v libx264 out.mp4

I was received a message: "No output pad can be associated to link label '0:v'. Error initializing complex filters. Invalid argument".

I hope to receive your help,
Thank you so much.

P/s: alike this video

[image: transition effect in ffmpeg]

Comment: There's a semi-colon missing between `[black]` and `[o:v]`. However, I see other issues with the command. Your filtergraph operates on two inputs but your command only supplies one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually I can not understand fully in my command (I just studied from another). I appreciate so much if you can help me with alternative ways. Thank you.